# VSCode settings not taking effect randomly in multi-root workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am using VSCode to work within a monorepo structure using workspaces. The root contains a `.code-workspace` file with some settings configured and projects are defined as their own workspaces and contain a `.vscode` folder with a `settings.json` file and other build tasks etc.

In the `settings.json` file for each project/workspace along with in the `.code-workspace` file there some settings of the following form:

```
"settings": {
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
         "Path": ${config:VAR1};${config:VAR2};${config:VAR3};${env:PATH}
    },
    "VAR1": "path/to/var1",
    "VAR2": "path/to/var2",
    "VAR3": "path/to/var3",
}
```

I know that this setup does work as I usually have never had any trouble with it but as of recently I have had a lot of trouble with these paths seemingly not being defined. For example one of the projects has some build tasks which utilize tools located at these paths (GNU Make to be specific) which I get an error saying the tool was not found. Sometimes reloading the window helps but recently restarting my PC did not even solve the issue. The problem has been frustrating me as of recently and I'd like to solve the issue if possible. Could someone give possible reasons why this issue would occur ? I am no VSCode expert and don't fully understand how the workspace settings are organized and whether the workspace file settings take priority etc as I did not create this structure.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Also, can you reproduce this issue in a regular, non-multi-root workspace?

Comment: Since I posted I determined that the issue is most definitely due to the multi-root workspace. If I open a project as a regular workspace, its build tasks run perfectly fine. I can get it to work in the multi-root workspace if I specify the PATH environment variable in the actual build task